# proving equality between functions

Tags: calculus, alternative-proof

If we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ $\exists y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y\geq x$ and $|f(y)|\geq 1$ We call it type A.

A function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined where $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $y\geq x$ and $|g(y)|\geq 1$ is of type B.

**(user2661923 : start of question)** 
This is a point of confusion - I ask the OP to edit his question to resolve the confusion and (at the same time), remove this section of his query.

For type-B functions, does the OP intend that $\forall y, |g(y)| \geq 1$?

I am unable to find an interpretation of the OP's description of type-B functions that does not have the above constraint as a consequence. 
**(user2661923 : end of question)**

Now my question is how do I prove this using contradiction/direct proof that if a function is type A then its type B and the converse (type B then type A).

I've done it with a counterexample, but I want to prove it without using a counterexample if thats possible.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 \quad\text{if} \quad x\in\mathbb{N}\\2\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

edits:

Type $B$ is where $\exists x$ real, such that for all $y$ real $y\geq x$ such that $|g(y)|\geq 1$

type $A$ is where $\forall x$ real, $\exists y$ real, with $y\geq x$ such that $|f(y)|\geq 1$

If a function of type $A$ then it s type $B$ and if a function is type $B$ then it is type $A$

Comment: Your type $B$ introduces $x$ but does not use it.  The condition, $|g(y)|≥1$ does not depend on $x$, so, as written, you are just asking that $|g(y)|≥1$ for all $y$

Comment: If you've found a counter example than then that proves the statement is false.

Comment: @fleablood, yes that is true. But my question was if there is an alternate way to prove this, as in direct proof or a contradiction

Comment: How can you prove it at all if it is false?

Comment: I'm not getting the problem.  Type A just seems to means no matter what $x$ you pick there will always be a larger $y$ so that $|f(x)| \ge 1$.   And type $B$ seems to be whatever $y$ you pick $|g(y)| \ge 1$.

Comment: no i meant, prove that type $A$ does not imply type $B$

Comment: As written, it is obvious that the two types are different.  But, as I mentioned, I expect you intended your type $B$ to be something other than what you wrote.

Comment: there shoudn't be any difference if i say type $B$ $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ ...?

Comment: A function will never be type $B$ if $|g(x)|$ is ever less than $1$.  But a function can be type $B$ so long as there are infintely many $|f(x)|\ge 1$.  But a function is type $B$ it's obviously type $A$ as $|g(x)|$ can never not be less than $1$.  (as written; I'm with lulu that you *must* have written the problem wrong as type B has nothing to do with $x$ and just say $|g(y)|\ge 1$ for all $y$.)

Comment: **To the OP** I have inserted edits directly into your question, trying to resolve a possible point of confusion.  Please edit your query accordingly.

Comment: I made an edit section hopefully to clear any confusion

Comment: I'm sorry, you did **not** confront the specific question that I was asking - does type B require that for all $y, |f(y)| \geq 1.$  Please confront that question, remove the pertinent portion of my editing to your query, and **re-write** your specification of type-B functions to directly answer that question.